# invalidate a NSTimer object after visiting from another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, pthreads

**Situation**

I have two view controller *VC1* and *VC2*.
In *VC1* I need to call a selector continuously with ***x seconds*** interval upto ***t seconds (where x < t)***.

I am using `NSTimer` object to manage it. If I am in the *VC1* then the `NSTimer` object is working fine. It is calling it self after ***x second***. Here is my code

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(methodName) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Also I can stop the also by `[timer invalidate];`

**Question:**

Now I am going to *VC2* and then again back to *VC1*.

How to stop the `timer` in *VC1*?

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you really asking for where to hook code before and after a view controller is presented and then returns?  It doesn't really matter what that code does and therefore mentioning `NSTimer` is irrelevant.  Or have I missed something?

Comment: when you want to stop timer? when goes to vc2 ? or when come to vca from vc2 ?

Comment: There is no fixed timing to stop timer or go to vc2. All are random in between t seconds.

Comment: @intsoumen How you go to VC2 from VC1?, by `prepareForSegue` or storyboard .

Comment: @Ahmed I am using `segue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the timer in use

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
     [timer invalidate]
 }
```

Comment: Yes I can. But I need it to run it in background. Thank you.

Comment: I think, your question is not clear what are you asking ?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using delegate.

You just need to create a delegate in VC2 and then implement in VC1 and in the delegate method(in VC1) you just need to invalidate `NSTimer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this By implementing forword declaration

`@class VC1`  to **VC2** and create one `BOOL` property in VC1

now set `VC1.property = true` when you push **VC1** from **VC2**

now in viewWillAppear method check this boolean property in **VC1**

if this property is true than `invalidate timer` and also set `nil` to your `timer` object.

Hope this helps you easily.

Answer (score 0):

In VC1.h

```
@property bool timer validate;
```

in VC1.m put this code when you call VC2

```
_timervalidate=true;
```

after it use viewWillAppear Method to stop timer

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(_timervalidate==true)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```